# Access skill tree in Trine 2 without leveling up?

Tags: trine-2

In the skill tree, it's possible to reset skills, and I'd like to do so. However, I can't seem to find a way of accessing the skill tree unless I've just leveled up.

Is there a way, such as a menu entry I can't seem to find, to access the skill tree at will?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the tab key (<kbd>`↹`</kbd>) to open the Skill menu